# How to increase the throughput of elastic beanstalk server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma, rds

Here is my configuration for **elastic beanstalk**:

We are using `Elastic Beanstalk` with **ngnix puma** on **m3.medium** instances for our Rails application based on **Ruby-2.2.3** and **Rails 3.2.22**.

We are using **m4.large** **RDS** for **postgresql** server with 3000 provisional IOPS and **300 Storage** space.

The **max_pool** for database connection is set to **20**. 
Our database shows it allows around 250 connections.

Still, our server gets `5xx error`s and the **load balancer** instances spin up frequently. Our IOPS consumption is always high. During a large product pull from FTP locations, the **Read IOPS** goes up to **3000 IOPS** and **write IOPS** goes up to **400 IOPS**.

The **`production log`** shows that the 5xx errors are generated because of no connection available to the database. Max connection is set to 20. Please consider to increase it.

For product pulling we have implemented batch product search(upto 30 products) instead of searching single product every time.

This IOPS is also high when the product pull is also not running.

We have also implemented `Elastic Cache`,  `Delayed Job`, `Fragment Caching`
, `Eager Loading` etc. to optimize our code.

**Possible Reasons:**
We have

- around **6 million** products We pull around **1 million products** everyday
  during EST night time.
- We are using **sunspot solr** in a separate server which reindex the products once in a week.
- Number of requests as per EBS report is 7.2K per hour

Comment: How is you database.yml looks like? Do you have timeout settings in the database.yml? Any issue to increase the Pool to a higher number?

Comment: We do not have timeout setting in database.yml. We have only setting for max pool size which is set to 30. Now the number of database connections goes upto 61.

Comment: Facing similar issues here. Did you figure this out? Thanks!